# How to stop TabBar hidden in change focus in tvos

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, tvos, apple-tv, swift2

I am working on apple tv app in swift. I need to implement TabBarController. In apple tv application TabBar hidden in change focus but I want to need show TabBar if user change focus in app.
How to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method in UITabBarController Class

```
 override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator){

   self.tabBar.hidden = false

}
```

Comment: Can you implement this method in  UITabBarController Class.

Comment: @vipulk617 your solution didn't work for me as well.